# How to rollback dataframe.to_sql in python in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@host:5432/database')
transactions.to_sql('transactions', engine,if_exists='append',index=False,method='multi')
```

How do I rollback this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can begin a transaction before calling `to_sql` and then do a rollback afterwards:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@mssqlLocal64")

def dump_tran_test_table(conn):
    print(conn.execute(sa.text("SELECT * FROM tran_test")).fetchall())

# set up test environment
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tran_test")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "CREATE TABLE tran_test "
        "(txt varchar(10), id int primary key)"
    )
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        "INSERT INTO tran_test (txt, id) VALUES "
        "('old_foo', 1), ('old_bar', 2)"
    )

# test
with engine.connect() as conn:
    tran = conn.begin()
    df = pd.DataFrame([("new_baz", 3)], columns=["txt", "id"])
    df.to_sql("tran_test", conn, index=False, if_exists="append")
    dump_tran_test_table(conn)
    """console output:
    [('old_foo', 1), ('old_bar', 2), ('new_baz', 3)]
    """
    tran.rollback()
    dump_tran_test_table(conn)
    """console output:
    [('old_foo', 1), ('old_bar', 2)]
    """
```

Comment: Hey gord, this looks good will try this. One doubt I had was that after df.to_sql here, do I need to commit this or it gets automatically committed?

Comment: If you explicitly `.begin` a transaction then yes, you need to explicitly `.commit` it.

Comment: Hello Gord, could you show where in this code we need to commit it?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore "AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'connect'" when you pass in `conn` to `.to_sql`

Comment: Hi @TomMedhurst - I just tested this example with SQLAlchemy 2.0.19 and pandas 2.0.3 and it worked fine. What versions are you running?