# Bulk insert using sqlalchemy Engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to bulk-insert/update values into a Microsoft SQLserver Database using Engine?

I have read several (very) old posts regarding this, and it seems not very easy to do (back then).

E.g in some examples we need to create a class, add those classes to a session and at last commit the session.

Isn't there a way like (pseudo) this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Float

values= [(1,"hello",2.5),(2,"world",10.5)] #values to insert
table = "my_schema.my_table"   #Table name
col = ["id","statement","ratio"]   #Name of the columns in the database
type = [Integer,String,Float]   #Type of each value

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)

with engine.session():
  try:
     engine.bulk_insert(table,values,col,type)
  except:
     engine.rollback()
```

or something else, instead of looping over `engine.execute("INSERT INTO ...")`?

I know I can use `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` but since I want to be able to roll-back in case of errors etc. I won't use that

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442600/2144390

Comment: To "instead of looping over `engine.execute("INSERT INTO ...")`", SQLA supports "executemany" operations: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements